# How to export Janusgraph/titan data result to a CSV file in hdfs location?

Tags: csv, hbase, titan, janusgraph

Is there any way we can save result of janusgraph/titan Graph Data as CSV format instead of hbase/cassandra table?
i couldn't find any proper document to save CSV file format.